# What is 'Maximal length of created query' in exporting a database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and I want to export all of the data from the database. Does the property 'Maximal length of created query' affect the amount of data you export?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It does affect the size of the exported file somewhat. The only thing that happens is that it limits the number of inserted rows per `INSERT` statement. So you end up with more, smaller statements.

[Here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/export)'s some info from their wiki:

> The option 'Maximal length of created query' seems to be undocumented.
>   But experiments has shown that it splits large extended INSERTS so
>   each one is no bigger than the given number of bytes (or characters?).
>   Thus when importing the file, for large tables you avoid the error
>   "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes". See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: All my inserts in my exported file are singular like this INSERT INTO `follower` VALUES(46071, 52, 43646, 1);. Even though the limit is set to 50000.

Comment: Maybe it's very careful to stay under the threshold? Seriously though, I seem to remember there's a separate toggle that allows you to choose whether it puts each insert in its own separate statement, but I could be wrong. I don't usually pay much attention to the "maximal length" option.

Comment: @BorutFlis in case you hadn't figured it out already, you need to check the "extended inserts" box when exporting. This combines multiple rows into one INSERT statement, and phpMyAdmin won't do this if you leave it unchecked.